# Why no Angular-CLI generate command for 'model' in Angular Project?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

While learning up Angular I just went through the various Angular-CLI commands to generate individual parts of Angular like 'Component', 'Services', 'Interface', 'Pipes', etc.

**Generating Angular Items via Angular-CLI**

```
ng g c components/comp-1 //generates component
ng g s services/service-1 // generates service
ng g i interfaces/interface-1 // generates interface
```

But, I am amazed why there is no generate command for '**Model**' (though Interface also does nearly some work -- but model is more powerful as can contain methods also in Class).

Am I missing something or Team-Angular missed on generating a command for 'automatically generating Models' -- as they are at the very core of OOPS Framework.

[image]

**Reference:**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli

Answer (score 249, accepted):

Because a model *is* a class, to generate it use `--type` option like this:

```
ng generate class hero --type=model
```

will result in:

```
hero.model.ts
```

Comment: But, then interface, pipes, modules are also clases. Aren't they?

Comment: You are correct, they technically are. But a model is the closest to a generic class by being a skeleton of data (But this isn't an excuse really). I'm amazed as well they didn't just add the `model` command albeit it isn't a reserved word or anything.

Comment: If you need to avoid creating unit test class hero.model.spec.ts simply type --spec=false. For example, ng generate class hero --type=model --spec=false

Comment: FYI this doesn't work with the shortened version: `ng g c hero --type=model`. You have to type everything out like in the answer.

Comment: @Patrick You only have to type out the word 'class'.  So in your example type:

    `ng g class hero --type=model`

and you will get your hero.model.ts and the associated .spec file

Comment: Thanks. Weird that `g` can be abbreviated but not `c`.

Comment: @Patrick that's because the abbreviation `c` is for `component` (and `s` is for `service`).
The command I often use is `ng generate interface hero --type=model` or  `ng generate i hero --type=model` because it creates an interface instead (and it does not create the spec/test file).

Comment: The argument spec does not seem to work in Angular 17.

Answer (score 19):

You cannot generate a model directly. Actually model is a class.
ng generate allows only following types to generate by default.

1. appShell
2. application
3. class
4. component
5. directive
6. enum
7. guard
8. interface
9. library
10. module
11. pipe
12. service
13. serviceWorker
14. universal
15. webWorker

So in your case you can use --type option to define a generate classes.
Let's assume you want a class like bar.foo.ts

You just have to define it with following option.

```
ng generate class bar --type=foo
```

in your case you can define a module with this command

```
ng generate class nameOfYourModule --type=model
```

It will generate nameOfYourModule.model.ts

Please refer this official [documentation](https://angular.io/cli/generate) of ng generate options for more informations.

Answer (score 5):

```
ng g class subfolder/yourclass --type=model --skip-tests
```

will create a class `yourclass` in `app\subfolder`. If you remove `--skip-tests`, you will get an extra file `yourclass.model.spec.ts`.

Answer (score 3):

Just run in root of project:

```sh
ng generate interface your_model_name --type=model
# or in models folder
ng generate interface models/your_model_name --type=model
```

Answer (score 1):

I just use `ng generate class` (without any flags), and I believe many others do as well.  I think the only time I use a pure class file in Angular is with models.  Since they are mostly in the models folder, there's little reason to add additional suffix of 'model' by using `--type=model`.   I believe that's part of the reasons why the Angular team did not include the 'ng generate model' command (since it is duplicative of class).

Answer (score 0):

This command also generate model

`ng generate class employee --type`

Result In:

`employee.ts`
`employee.spec.ts`